# Adding flag to Activity in Java

Tags: java, android, react-native, module, native

I am not Java developer but i need to implement some Android native module to my application, which is third party library.

I call @ReactMethod which should process the payment.

```
@ReactMethod
void processPayment(Boolean showTransactionResult, Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {
    Log.d("Message string", String.valueOf("Payment processing started "));
    ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();
    TransactionCallback callback = null; //?
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    Log.d("Current activity", String.valueOf(currentActivity));
    try {
        makeSale(context, showTransactionResult, callback);
        successCallback.invoke("Callback : payment successful");
    } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e){
        errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This Java function should open the payment window in front of the application.

```
void makeSale(ReactApplicationContext context, boolean showTransactionResult, TransactionCallback callback){
    Map<String, String> extras = new HashMap<>();
    extras.put("KEY_1", "Value 1");
    extras.put("KEY_2", "Value 2");
    PaymentSystem.getInstance().makeSale(context, true, extras, new TransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Map<String, String> map) {
            //Sale successful
            //data is transaction key
            //extras is the Map passed in makeSale()
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(PaymentSystemException e, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Map<String, String> map) {
            //Sale failed
        }
    });
}
```

But i am having this error message:

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1018)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:994)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:403)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:403)
    at digital.paynetics.paymentSystem.paymentSystemSdkMock.launchCallbackMockActivity(:5)
    at digital.paynetics.paymentSystem.paymentSystemSdkMock.makeSale(:2)
    at com.myapp.paymentSystemModule.makeSale(paymentSystemModule.java:118)
    at com.myapp.paymentSystemModule.processPayment(paymentSystemModule.java:82)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I found the solution on the internet which easy adding the flag to a Intent in Activity. But i dont know how to do it. I suppose Intent is a part of the third party library.

Please help me. Sorry for the dump question if it is only some Java issue.

Comment: Have you created custom native classes like Package and Module for creating custom native modules ?

Comment: Yes, the module itself works fine. These function are part of class PaymentSystemModule and PaymentSystemPackage is registered in MainApplication class.

Comment: I have posted an answer please have a look and tell me whether it is working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to use the getCurrentActivity to open new activity instead of getApplicationContext.

for ex.

```
makeSale(currentActivity, showTransactionResult, callback);
```